# Changing the profile picture of google from my website

Tags: google-plus, google-api-client

I have website where i enabled login by Google+ using OAuth 2. Is this possible to change the profile picture of Google from my website once he get login?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: i think no. If it is possible, I will try to avoid your website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm.. ya it can be possible if your site use application which uses Google Apps-Profiles-Data-API. This Profile data api allow update status. But you must authorize the app.

yo can find more more here- 
[Profile data API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/profiles/#Updating)